# Вопросы на понимание принципов построения СУБД

Tags: база-данных, sql

Читал на просторах Интернета, что среди вопросов на работу (junior-developer) бывает и такие:

> 1. Что такое первая нормальная форма и процесс нормализации? Какие бывают нормальные формы?
> 2. В чем смысл индекса СУБД, как они устроены, как хранятся? Как бы вы реализовали тот же функционал? Последний вопрос задают в случае, если нет четкого понимания индексов.

Ответ честно скажу - не знаю. Собственно в ответе на эти вопросы и заключается мой вопрос.

Ещё я напишу ту мешанину, которая у меня образовалась в голове при попытке найти ответы на эти вопросы, возможно, найдётся **добрый (очень добный)** человек и подскажет, в чём я заблуждаюсь.

Вот, что я предполагаю под некоторыми понятиями: по поводу первого знаю, что есть *6 нормальных форм + Бойса-Кодда и ДКНФ*.

- Знаю, что *первая нормальная форма* (н.ф.) - это невозможность нахождения двух идентичных строк в таблице и содержание в каждом поле лишь одного значения.
- Приведение ко *второй форме* - это, возможно, вынесение из таблицы первой нормальной формы всех неключевых полей с повторяющимися значениями в отдельную таблицу (через внешний ключ).
- *Третья* - это вторая н.ф. с отсутствием слабо связанных с ключом полей (т.е., например, зависящих от одного ключевого столбца и независящих от второго ключевого столбца при ключе по нескольким столбцам).
- *Бойса-Кодда* - это третья н.ф., в которой отсутствует потенциальная возможность установить ключ по другим столбцам.
- *Четвёртая* - это форма, удовлетворяющая правилу Бойса-Кодда и в которой отсутствует следующая избыточность, заключающаяся в обязательном присутсвии строки *b* при условии наличия в таблице строки *a*.
- *Пятая* - это четвёртая, в которой, как я читал, все возможные вынесения полей в отдельные таблицы сделаны, но, что это значит, я понятия не имею (ведь это вроде бы сделано во второй н.ф.).
- *Шестая* - понятия не имею. Что это? О_о
- *Доменно-ключевая нормальная форма* - это состояние базы данных, в которой, при условии выполнения определённых ограничений, никаким запросом нельзя нарушить целостность. Здесь речь идёт, насколько я понимаю, не о целостности информации в базе данных, а о целостности базы данных, и я не знаю, как сформулировать это определение в отношении б.д.

Со вторым вопросом мои познания ещё меньше: я привык, что *create index* пишется в случае, если необходимо увеличить скорость поиска по этим столбцам и уменьшить скорость добавления и удаления строк в эти таблицы. Когда начал читать, с удивлением для себя обнаружил, что бывают кластерные и некластерные индексы. Я предполагаю, что первые выглядят в виде таблицы с первыми значениями индексируемых полей с каждой страницы из кучи, напротив которых указаны номер файла и страницы. Некластерные индексы - честно говоря, не представляю, что это... Вроде видел описание, как дерева из двух уровней, на пером из которых то же, что и у кластерных индексов, а на втором - страницы с индексируемыми значениями, напротив которых указанны номер файла, страницы и строки из кучи, где эта запись строки находится... Но даже если на секунду предположить, что что-то из написанного имеет место быть, то зачем такая реализация некластерных индексов нужна, мне не удалось предположить.

Comment: По нормальным формам, самое правильнеое определение графическое с отрицанием. Т.е. Вот такой набор данных **не** находится в такой-то НФ из-за... Кстати сказать, нормальные формы относятся не к базам данных (в отличие от индексов), а к моделям данных, которые вовсе могут не быть БД.  

Про индексы, кластерные/некластерные - это не то, о чем вопрос, т.е. ни смысл ни строение "кластерность" не определяет. и да, все зависит в итоге от субд.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, НФ таки-имеет всякое отношение к реляционной модели данных, а реляционная модель данных каким-то непостижимым образом связана с реляционными базами данных, а некоторые люди до сих пор уверены, что нет баз данных, кроме реляционных баз данных, и Эдвард Кодд творец их.

Так что НФ всё-таки всяко относятся к СУБД, хотя, конечно, не возбраняется применять их где-то ещё.

Comment: @Andrey759, теоретические основы баз данных - весьма обширная тема.

Крайне рекомендую ознакомиться с этой книгой:

![alt text](http://i.imgur.com/0XUC3bO.jpg)

или хотя бы пройти [онлайн-курс](https://class.stanford.edu/courses/DB/2014/SelfPaced/about) от ее соавтора.

Comment: @MrClon, не совсем понятна ваша ирония и ваше уточнение. Что вы хотели донести? Что модель данных = СУБД?

Answer (score 2):

| НФ | Требование | Примечание |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Отсутствие множественных значений | Т.е. такого значения как "Nick, Mike, Alex" быть не должно |
| 2 | Отсутствие зависимости неключевых атрибутов от части составного ключа | По определению получается, что наличие id автоматически приводит таблицу к соответствию этому требованию т.к. это несоставной ключ |
| 3 | Отсутствие зависимости неключевых атрибутов от других неключевых атрибутов | - |
| BCNF (3.5) | Все функциональные зависимости (ФЗ) в отношении должны включать Super Key | В отношении "A, B, C" есть 2 ФЗ: А -> В и А -> С. Для соответствия 3.5НФ атрибут А обязательно должен быть Super Key |
| 4 | Отсутствие multi-valued зависимостей (multi-valued зависимость - это когда 2 атрибута зависят от 3-его, но не зависят друг от друга) | Отношение "Пиццерия, Сорт пиццы, Район доставки" не в 4НФ, т.к. "Сорт пиццы" и "Район доставки" зависят от "Пиццерия" и не зависят друг от друга |
| 5 | Отношение находится в 5НФ, когда дальнейшая декомпозиция (на подтаблицы) невозможна. Т.е оно уже максимально декомпозировано | По крайней мере невозможно без потери данных |

Кроме описанных требований есть общее требование для всех НФ - соответствие предыдущей НФ (т.е. 3-я НФ предполагает обязательное соответствие 2-й НФ).

Примечание для лучшего понимания таблицы:

- Функциональная зависимость (ФЗ) - в таблице "A, B" есть ФЗ "A -> B", если каждому уникальному значению A соответствует только 1 определенное значение B. Т.е. по А мы точно знаем, какое В.
- SuperKey - это 1 или несколько атрибутов, которые уникально идентифицируют кортеж в отношении.
- Primary Key - это Super Key, состоящий из минимально возможного количества атрибутов.

---

**Index** - это объект БД, который служит для ускорения поиска.

- Индекс представляет из себя структуру данных.
- Индекс должен создаваться на то поле, по которому происходит поиск. Или на несколько полей, если поиск по нескольким.
- Индекс положительно влияет только на скорость SELECT. На скорость INSERT и UPDATE он влияет отрицательно.
- Индекс влияет на скорость операций с WHERE и JOIN. На HAVING не влияет.
- Работа индекса м.б. основана на Binary Tree, B-Tree, HashMap и Bitmap